# How can I create API that returns canvas .png without browser?

Tags: json, node.js, api, canvas, openlayers-3

I need to create API which will input json file with features, and output will be png image (or base64) which will represent canvas of OpenLayers 3 map (`canvas.toDataUrl()`). I don't need to show map in the browser or even open the browser. Just API as some url /api/getMapImage which will return image of input json. I want to use NodeJS. I already have javascript which do all required actions (like defining map, taking canvas as image).

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Check out [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what exactly you want to do and how, with no code examples and info on what you have tried so far, so I can only point you in hopefully the right direction:

There is a [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) module that lets you do things like [this example](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#example):

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , Image = Canvas.Image
  , canvas = new Canvas(200, 200)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = '30px Impact';
ctx.rotate(.1);
ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

var te = ctx.measureText('Awesome!');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
ctx.lineTo(50 + te.width, 102);
ctx.stroke();

console.log('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
```

You can also check [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444122/nodejs-web-scraping-form-submittion/37444895#37444895) about web scraping modules in Node. They can access web pages with JS in them but without opening a browser windows - maybe it's a way that would work better in your case if you need some other browser-specific JS to run.

Also, there is the [openlayers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers) npm module that can be useful to you.

It's hard to be more specific having such a vague question but hopefully you'll get somewhere.